# Using Ajax to store checkbox in database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

Update: The code is working. I had an incorrectly named table in my php file.

I have the following that I've found from some snippets during my searches for help however I cannot get it to work. What I am trying to accomplish is clicking a check box and it automatically populate a row in my database that I can refer to on any other page. Right now when I click the checkbox, nothing happens.

HTML

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $brow['WorkOrder']; ?>"  value="<?php echo $brow['WorkOrder']; ?>"></td>
```

Ajax

```
     <!-- Checkbox storage -->
     <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function(){
        var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
        if(checked){
            var value = $(this).val();
            $.post('functions/checkBox.php', { value:value }, function(data){
                // data = 0 - means that there was an error
                // data = 1 - means that everything is ok
                if(data == 1){
                    // Do something or do nothing :-)
                    alert('Data was saved in db!');
                }
            });
        }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

functions/checkBox.php

```
<?php
if ($_POST && isset($_POST['value'])) {

    // db connection
    include("../../db.php");

    // sanitize the value
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value']);

    // start the query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO TemporaryCheckBoxID (WorkOrder) VALUES ('$value')";

    // check if the query was executed
    if(mysql_query($sql)){
       // everything is Ok, the data was inserted
       print(1);    
    } else {
       // error happened
       print(0);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "nothing happens"?  Is there an error in the JavaScript code?  Is the AJAX request made?  Does it have the data you expect?  What is the server's response?  What is the SQL query being executed at runtime?  Is the MySQL server returning an error?  (Hint: You're not checking)  Where/how *specifically* does this fail?

Comment: It's not making the alert, even when reversed to 0 to give the alert if there is an error and nothing shows. Nothing shows in the chrome console and no error_log file gets generated.

Comment: Ok, so it doesn't reach the `alert()` in the callback.  What *does* it do?  There are a number of `if` statements in which that `alert()` is nested.  Maybe one of them is `false`?  When you debug this, where does it fail?

Comment: Do those checkboxes exist when the page renders or they are created afterwards?

Comment: They exist before the <script> if that is what you mean

Comment: @David I added some more alerts and it stops when it gets to if(data == 1){

Comment: @JohnLang: And what is the runtime value of `data`?  It seems reasonable that if `if (data == 1)` is false then `data` *probably* equals something other than 1.

Comment: In your php code print(1) is executed when query runs.

Comment: Oh... I figured it out. It was an incorrectly named table in my php file. @David THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

To check whether checkbox is checked or not use as below and try

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function(){
        var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
        if(checked){
            var value = $(this).val();
            $.post('functions/checkBox.php', { value:value }, function(data){
                // data = 0 - means that there was an error
                // data = 1 - means that everything is ok
                if(data == 1){
                    // Do something or do nothing :-)
                    alert('Data was saved in db!');
                }
            });
        }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Same results, no alert happens

Comment: can you check the ajax call on the network tab of chrome developer tools and see if it is successful after checkbox click, if it is not successful you wont get the alert, if you are not able to check network tab.. try to use `$.ajax` with success and error functions to check if the ajax is successful or not..